# Regex - Match sentence avoiding parentheses

Tags: regex, keyword, parentheses, sentence

I would need to make a regex to match the keywords inside a big text.

An example of the big text could be the following:

> ...another sentence ending Keywords: tag 1, tag 2, tag 3 (may contain
>   something like this ref. 1), tag 4 and tag 5. Another sentence
>   has begun...

The regex has to extract:

> Keywords: tag 1, tag 2, tag 3 (may contain
>   something like that ref. 1), tag 4 and tag 5

I have the following code:

```
\bKeywords:[^\.]+
```

But the problem is that the regex is not avoiding the text inside the parentheses and stops with the dot on "..ref. 1..".

Thank you all!

Note: The word "tag" it is an example, it could be any word.

Comment: Can you try this `Keywords: (tag \d\s?(\(.*\))?(,|and)?\s?)+`?

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply!

The word "tag" it is an example, it could be any word.

Comment: So this should work? `Keywords: (.+ \d\s?(\(.*\))?(,|and)?\s?)+`

Comment: It doesn't work :/

Here you have a real example of a big text:

... Keywords: absorption, ASTM specifications, calcium silicate brick, compressive strength, concrete brick, dimensions, face shell and web thick - ness, gross area, net area, specifications, testing, water absorption 2012 editions of the International Building Code (IBC) (ref. 1), as well as the most current ASTM edition. Code officials will commonly...

Comment: Try `\bKeywords:.*(?=\.\s[A-Z])`

Comment: It is weird due on sublime works awesome but I'm trying to do this over PHP and here doesn't work.

Comment: I found why it is happening: there are more sentences after the ".. Code officials will .." and the regex it is getting all of those

Comment: May parentheses be nested?

Comment: Look, if you run that regex on this text, you gonna get extra sentences: Keywords: lorem, ipsum, another tag (something inside parentheses ref. 1). A sentence as example. Another sentence as example. Another sentence as example 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming parantheses can't be nested: [`Keywords: (?:[^(.]|\([^)]*\))*`](https://regex101.com/r/3uEh3p/1).

I'm matching:

```
(?:[^(.]|\([^)]*\))*
                   * as many times as possible
(?:               )  non-capturing
        |            either:
   [^(.]             a character that's not an opening paranthesis or a dot, or
         \(     \)   inside literal parantheses
           [^)]*     as many characters that aren't closing parantheses as possible
```

If parantheses *can* be nested, then regex is not what you want, because the language you try to capture is [context-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar).

Comment: It works! Thank you to you and to the other guy that tried to help me!